# openvpn admin clients to see all other clients

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn

I've setup an openvpn with all special configuration, everything is fine, however i stuck on iptable rules.what i want to do is to have two seperate client groups, one of them is for regular customer clients, other covers admin clients , i need to restrict customer clients to see each other while admin clients can reach all other clients to diagnose the issues of those customer clients.

i firstly disabled client-to-client option and added some rules to iptables.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If i would want to allow communication between two clients, i would add something like that:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.2 -d 10.8.0.4 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

because i want to have admin clients, i assigned static ip to certain clients, let's say this admin client has 10.8.0.5 ip adress.what should i do to forward this static ip to all subnet, whatever ip address other clients have, this admin client should see and reach these clients. i couldn't exactly figure it out.

Comment: In my opinion you should allow in openvpn client-to-client, and using iptables allow traffic from Admin IP to client subnet, and disable client-to-client traffic. But generally, it could be easier to make separate tunnels for admins and users (if you can do this), and use for example Shorewall to manage iptables rules.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, i managed to do it by disabling client-to-client option. when i did so, the packet goes to kernel, so to iptable rules i set. I selected some admin clients and assigned them static ip , in the next step, i only accept this ip adresses of admin clients at iptable, so when a normal client try to connect the other one, its packets drop in kernel, but if an admin client with static ip try to connect, its packets are accepted and forward to the destination source.